# combining node.js and three.js on server side

Tags: node.js, three.js

I'm trying to make a simple app that renders a cube with three.js on a node.js, for this i have tryed [node-three.js](https://github.com/nulltask/node-three.js) which basically wraps three.js, creates a simulated browser window, and exposes THREE variable so you can use it.
The problem is that i keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" so i narrowed it down to this code:

```
var THREE = require('three.js');

firstVec = new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2);
secondVec = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1);

clonedVec = firstVec.clone();
clonedVec.sub(secondVec); //this line is where the error occurs
```

the error message is:

```
undefined:818
                this.x = a.x - b.x;
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

which (to my understanding) suggests that the second vector can't be identified by THREE module.
Anyone who tried this method: were you able to make it work?
*In order to make it work under Linux, you should edit the /lib/three.js file:
line #10 should be edited:

```
  , src = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../deps/three.js/build/three.js') //three.js instead of Three.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved using the original implementation of [three.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/three). first you:
 
`npm install three`
and then replace: 
 
`var THREE = require('three.js');`
 
with: 
`var THREE = require('three');`